# How do I change between Excel worksheets in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

[image]

I am trying to create VBScript which will fetch data from one tab in Excel and that data will replace a particular string available in another tab of the Excel sheet.

1. I have created an Excel containing two worksheets "Data" and "Query".
2. In Query tab there is one column "Queryine" and position of the column is B or 2 which contains this below string.

   ```
   Select account from table1 where columname=<<field>>
   ```
3. In data tab "field" variable is available containing value 10.
4. `<<field>>` needs to be replaced by this value 10. so the above query need to display like this:

   ```
   Select account from table1 where columname=10
   ```

I have created this VBScript:

```
Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
objexcel.Visible = True
Set wb = objexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Datasheet.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Query")

Row = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To Row
    finalvalue = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value

    splitvalues = Split(finalvalue, " ")
    For j = 0 To UBound(splitvalues)
        correctvalue = splitvalues(j)

        If InStr(correctvalue, ">>") > 0 Then
            variablename = Trim(Replace(Replace(correctvalue, "<<", " "), ">>", " "))
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
            Col = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Row2 = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For k = 2 To Row2
                If variablename = ws.Cells(k, 1).Value Then
                    For P = 2 To Col
                        temp2 = ws.Cells(k, P).Value
                        Latestvalue = Trim(Replace(variablename, temp2))

                        Set fsoObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                        filepath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop"
                        Set MyFile =fsoObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Query.p", 1, True)
                        MyFile.Write Latestvalue
                        MyFile.Close
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            Set MyFile = Nothing
            Set fsoObject = Nothing
        End If
    Next
Next
wb.Close
objexcel.Quit
Set objexcel = Nothing
```

On trying to run the vbs file I am getting error:

> "unexpected Next"

Also I am not sure if I am able to navigate to "Data" tab from "Query" tab.

Comment: Indenting code makes it readable.

Comment: @Andreas i have indented and updated it in above post. but the code is not working.Not sure what is the error

Comment: I have attached images of the worksheets also for your reference

Comment: Just tried the code you posted, and it doesn't return that error for me. Are you sure this is the code that returns the error?